# Generate random number from $\log(f(x))$ rather than $f(x)$

Tags: random-variables, random

There are many tricks to be played when generating random numbers from a given distribution with density $f(x)$, ususally cases where you can perform an inverse transform of the primitive analytically, is by far the best.

Say that I cannot calculate this analytically, but I can see that for a given problem it is easily done for $\log(f(x))$, which unfortunately does not lead to a simple transformation rule for $x$, which I would know how to handle. My question is this: Is there a general trick which allows me to generate a number from $\log(f(x))$, and then transform the generated number back to be sampled from the desired distribution?

Comment: Is your $f(x)$ a density or a cumulative distribution function?  What is the particular given problem where for $\log(f(x))$ it is "easily done"?

Comment: I have clarified that it is the density. It could for example be a density $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ which cannot be integrated analytically, but $log(g)$ and $log(h)$ can, and then I can multichannel.

Comment: 1. Isn't $\log f=\log g+\log h$ ? This ensures the analytic integrability of $\log f$. 2. Why is $\log f$ a *probability* density if $f$ is one ?